# Don't have ADD IMAGE SEQUENCE option in Texture ( Shader )

Tags: animation

guys need help was creating rain effect by CG GEEK
but having an issue
i am not having ADD " image sequence " in texture so i cant add one please help

Comment: It's usually easier to communicate in sentences. If people can see you put effort into communication they might be more willing to help you and it is usually easier to understand as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the Shader Editor you can find it under Add -> Texture:

[image]

In the Compositor under Add -> Input:

[image]

Comment: For the newest, experimental Blender version, I can't find either of them

Comment: Well... Experimental builds are... experimental. That should not be a surprise. If he is talking about the experimental build, I don't think it is very smart to expect it to work perfectly fine or be surprised if it doesn't.